# Rheem water heater keeps locking out

Tags: plumbing, hvac, water-heater, gas

My Rheem water heater, model # PRO + G60S-55NCN62PV, keeps shutting down with this error -  `Maximum amount of ignition attempts has been reached and system is in lockout`. It was happening for around 6 weeks and every time we tried to restart it would work okay for next week or so.

I called a professional and they said it could be the flame sensor or the gas valve or something else. If someone had a similar experience can you please help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked and/or replaced any of the parts the professional indicated could be the issue? Of course, "or something else" is pretty obvious, too. Did the professional actually come to your house to inspect the heater, or was this just a phone conversation? If you're calling in a pro, it's _likely_ (though not guaranteed) that she'd actually know what she's doing and will get this fixed pronto.

Comment: Duplicate: [Rheem PowerVent Hot Water Heater - Ignition Attempt Error Code Resolution?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/127054/rheem-powervent-hot-water-heater-ignition-attempt-error-code-resolution?rq=1)

Comment: @FreeMan - thanks for your message. yes the professional actually came to my house about couple of weeks ago and at that time it showed an error for pressure switch but when the error came again this week it shows maximum ignition attempts have been reached. So after this error I had a phone conversation with the same pro who came over and he told me it’s a bit tricky because this particular error could be due to a number of reasons such as flame sensor or gas valve etc. so at this time we don’t have a permanent solution as per them. Not sure what else we can do.

Answer (score 0):

most common is a dirty or faulty flame detection sensor.

sometime it helps if it is cleaned.

If it reports no flame that would shut down the system and it will try again 5 times, before full shut down.

Comment: is flame detection sensor the thermocouple?

Comment: As fas as I know both do the same job but they are different parts